# Why isn't this removing the options?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm struggling to find the error within my code. My function is triggered whenever an option is changed. I first cycle through all the selects to see which values have been selected. I then cycle through them again and then their children to HIDE all the options that have been taken. I am sure that there are other posts on stack overflow that have better ways of doing this, but I would rather have my original code. I can't find my error, though. I have put alerts everywhere but they are always called only once, even though the `.length` is > 1.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

- I just realized the problem was with the `.removeAttr` so if anyone could tell me how to fix that, that might be just the help I need.

```js
$(document).on("change", function(e) {
  var hmmm = [];
  var facts = true;
  var allSelects = $(".student-three select");
  for (var i = 0; i < allSelects.length; i++) {
    if (allSelects[i].value != 0) {
      hmmm.push(allSelects[i].value);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < allSelects.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < allSelects[i].children.length; j++) {
      for (var z = 0; z < hmmm.length; z++) {
        if (allSelects[i].children[j].value == hmmm[z]) {
          allSelects[i].children[j].addAttr('hidden');
          facts = false;
        }
      }
      if (facts) {
        allSelects[i].children[j].removeAttr('hidden');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="student-three">
    Choice 1:
    <select name="C1">
      <option value='0'>Select One</option>
      <option value='1'>Option 1
      </option>
      <option value='2'>Option 2
      </option>
    </select><br>Choice 2:
    <select name="C2">
      <option value='0'>Select One</option>
      <option value='1'>Option 1
      </option>
      <option value='2'>Option 2 
      </option>
    </select><br>Choice 3:
    <select name="C3">
      <option value='0'>Select One</option>
      <option value='1'>Option 1 
      </option>
      <option value='2'>Option 2
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `$(document).on("change"` should be `$(document).on("change", ".student-three select", function(e) {`

Comment: I've changed that, but I'm afraid I still can't figure out why the removeAttr won't work.

Comment: OK let me see in depth

Comment: What is `facts` used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that jquery's operator `[]` not returns a jquery element; it returns a DOM element.

This element has no method `removeAttr()` (the equivalent is `removeAttribute()`), so you shoudl pass it to `$()` to get a jquery element.

Also, jquery hasn't `addAttr()` as opposite to `removeAttr()`. Instead, you should use `attr(<>, true)`. See [Add disabled attribute to input element using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806685/add-disabled-attribute-to-input-element-using-javascript).

```js
$(document).on("change", function(e) {
  var hmmm = [];
  var facts = true;
  var allSelects = $(".student-three select");
  for (var i = 0; i < allSelects.length; i++) {
    if (allSelects[i].value != 0) {
      hmmm.push(allSelects[i].value);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < allSelects.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < allSelects[i].children.length; j++) {
      for (var z = 0; z < hmmm.length; z++) {
        if (allSelects[i].children[j].value == hmmm[z]) {
          $(allSelects[i].children[j]).attr('hidden', true);
          facts = false;
        }
      }
      if (facts) {
        $(allSelects[i].children[j]).removeAttr('hidden');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="student-three">
    Choice 1:
    <select name="C1">
      <option value='0'>Select One</option>
      <option value='1'>Option 1
      </option>
      <option value='2'>Option 2
      </option>
    </select><br>Choice 2:
    <select name="C2">
      <option value='0'>Select One</option>
      <option value='1'>Option 1
      </option>
      <option value='2'>Option 2 
      </option>
    </select><br>Choice 3:
    <select name="C3">
      <option value='0'>Select One</option>
      <option value='1'>Option 1 
      </option>
      <option value='2'>Option 2
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Very nice. I would add a `facts = true` right after the for statement with the j. Otherwise the hidden/false code doesn't really do anything.

Answer (score 1):

- Cache your selector `const $allSelects = $(".student-three select");`
- `.map()` to array all the selected values
- Use `:gt(0)` to skip the first hint option
- use `.prop()` for the `"hidden"` property - with a callback with the needed logic
- Use `Array.includes()` to check if a value exists in the selected values array

```js
const $allSelects = $(".student-three select");

$allSelects.on("change", function() {

  const sel = $allSelects.get().map(el => el.value); // selected values to array
  $allSelects.find('option:gt(0)').prop('hidden', function() {
    return !this.selected && sel.includes(this.value);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<div class="student-three">
  Choice 1:
  <select name="C1">
    <option value='0'>Select One</option>
    <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Option 3</option>
  </select><br>Choice 2:
  <select name="C2">
    <option value='0'>Select One</option>
    <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Option 3</option>
  </select><br>Choice 3:
  <select name="C3">
    <option value='0'>Select One</option>
    <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```